# pathForResource doesn't return an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 methods, one for saving an array to a file and one for loading an array from the file, but when I'm trying to read an array, nothing happens, like an array is empty.
My code:

```
- (IBAction)write:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *array = [racersArray copy];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/history.plist"];
    [array writeToFile:location atomically:YES];
}

- (IBAction)read:(id)sender
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *array = (path != nil ? [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/history.plist"] : nil);
}
```

Comment: Compare the two file paths in your code carefully.

Comment: And that's why you would write a method "pathForHistoryPList" _once_ and use it where needed. To avoid stupid mistakes where "read" and "write" use different paths.

Answer (score 5):

You are reading/writing from/to two different places.

- You write to the `Library` folder (it should be under `Library/Application Support` or some such, but I digress).
- You read from the app bundle.

Comment: Yes, looks like that's true. But I don't know, how I should edit the line `NSString *path..` to do what it's supposed to.

Comment: @kolaj: Seriously? You have two methods that need the same parameter and don't know how to make that parameter the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Methods may be helps you.

For Save

```
-(IBAction)save_Action:(id)sender{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"manuallyData.plist"];
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

For Get Path

```
-(IBAction)retrive:(id)sender{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"manuallyData.plist"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
    {
         plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"manuallyData" ofType:@"plist"];
    }
}
```

Comment: stil returns empty array

Comment: let me check it once

Comment: Its working f9 just have look down kolaj i tested it

Comment: Please change "retrive" to "retrieve". There are many people here whose first language isn't English, and you don't want them to learn things that are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)savetapped:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"json.geojson"];
    [paths writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
- (IBAction)retriveTapped:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"json.geojson"];
    NSLog(@"%@",documentsPath);
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
    {
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"json" ofType:@"geojson"];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",plistPath );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to figure out that I don't actually know what you are trying to do.

pathForResource gives you paths for resource in your application bundle. You can only *read* from there. You can never write there. Sometimes people have the initial version of a file in the application bundle and then write it somewhere else. If that's what you want then most likely you need to:

(1) write a method that returns the path where the array will be stored once your application has been running.

(2) The "write" method calls this path method to know where to write the array.

(3) The "read" method calls this path method to know where to read the array, then you read it. However, the array can be nil because your app was run the first time, or the array wasn't written correctly. In that case, you use pathForResource to get the path where the file would be in your application bundle, and read it from there.